# How to get names from two ID's in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

| Subcat_id | Uppercat_id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 12 | Room 1 |

Query:

```
Select Subcat_id, Uppercat_id, Name
From Rooms
```

Where:

- Subcat_id is PK
- Name column has names for Subcat_id and Uppercat_id
- ID 45 - Room 1
- ID 12 - Conference Rooms

My goal is to get both Subcat_id nad Uppercat_id's names at the same time like this

| Subcat_id | Uppercat_id | Name (Subcat_id) | Name2 (Uppercat_id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 12 | Room 1 | Conference Rooms |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store a hierarchy of rooms in the table and you'd like to get the information about the upper level, then you can join the table with itself:

```
select subcat_level.subcat_id, subcat_level.name, subcat_level.uppercat_id,
       upper_level.name
from rooms as subcat_level
left join rooms upper_level on upper_level.subcat_id = subcat_level.uppercat_id
```

Comment: You are a hero Stanislav! Thank you!